# Managing different python scripts and calling them

Tags: python, python-2.7

For easy maintenance, I have separated python programs into different files.

Below  are python script file names:

```
  1.master.py
  2.setup.py
  3.core1.py
  4.core2.py
  5.standard.py
```

master.py:

```
   import setup
   import standard
   do something
```

setup.py:

```
   import standard
   a = 5
   b = 5 
   if standard.d == 10:
       do something
```

standard.py:

```
  import setup 
  if setup.a == 5:
      d = 10 
      do something
```

When we run master script it will import setup.py and setup.py will import standard.py. We will get error message setup.a is not defined.

I have two options to fix this issue.

1. Make single script for setup.py and standard.py
2. Change setup.py to:

   ```
   a = 5
   b = 5
   import standard 
   if standard.d == 10:
      do something
   ```

Option 2 is not best since python suggestion always import modules at very first of the the program.

Option 1 can be achievable but it be would great if have setup.py and standard.py separately.

Any suggestions will be help a lot. I am new to programming world. Hence i required experts suggestion, how they will manage this kind of situation.

Comment: Don't use circular imports. The two files are importing each other endlessly

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to separate objects that are supposed to be used by other scripts into functions (or even classes), then write the private body of the script.

The code would be like this:

master.py:

```
import setup
import standard

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do something
```

setup.py:

```
import standard

def a():
    return 5
def b():
    return 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if standard.d == 10:
        do something
```

standard.py:

```
import setup 

def d():
    if setup.a == 5:
        return 10
    else:
        print 'setup.a != 5'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if setup.a == 5:
        do something
```